# can i move modalpopextender edit form if yes then can I?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

Can i move modalpopextender edit form if yes then how can I ?

Comment: set PopupDragHandleControlID property to move the modalpopextender

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set PopupDragHandleControlID property to move the modalpopupextender